# how to set gVim to support unicode balloonexpr

Tags: vim

I want to display some unicode-text in gvim's balloon.

```
set balloonexpr=GTranslator()
set balloondelay=400
set ballooneval

fun! GTranslator()
    return '☺hello☻'
endfun
```

it cann't display `☺☻` properly.

---

Ver: gVim7.2(Window XP)

Comment: Is encoding set to utf8 (`:set encoding=utf-8`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, it works with my gvim 7.3

Windows XP SP3, 32 bit

I had this script sourced and the unicode characters showed just fine

```
set balloonexpr=GTranslator()
set balloondelay=400
set ballooneval

fun! GTranslator()
    return 'Hñø'
endfun
```

Here are settings I thought relevant:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Aug 15 2010 15:14:24)
MS-Windows 32-bit GUI version with OLE support
Compiled by Bram@KIBAALE
Big version with GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+arabic +autocmd +balloon_eval +browse ++builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent +clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments +conceal +cryptv 
+cscope +cursorbind +cursorshape +dialog_con_gui +diff +digraphs -dnd -ebcdic +emacs_tags +eval +ex_extra +extra_search +farsi +file_in_path +find_in_path +float +folding 
-footer +gettext/dyn -hangul_input +iconv/dyn +insert_expand +jumplist +keymap +langmap +libcall +linebreak +lispindent +listcmds +localmap -lua +menu +mksession +modify_fname 
+mouse +mouseshape +multi_byte_ime/dyn +multi_lang -mzscheme +netbeans_intg +ole -osfiletype +path_extra +perl/dyn +persistent_undo -postscript +printer -profile +python/dyn 
+python3/dyn +quickfix +reltime +rightleft +ruby/dyn +scrollbind +signs +smartindent -sniff +startuptime +statusline -sun_workshop +syntax +tag_binary +tag_old_static 
-tag_any_white +tcl/dyn -tgetent -termresponse +textobjects +title +toolbar +user_commands +vertsplit +virtualedit +visual +visualextra +viminfo +vreplace +wildignore +wildmenu
 +windows +writebackup -xfontset -xim -xterm_save +xpm_w32 
   system vimrc file: "$VIM\vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME\_vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "$VIM\_vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME\_exrc"
  2nd user exrc file: "$VIM\_exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM\gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME\_gvimrc"
2nd user gvimrc file: "$VIM\_gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME\menu.vim"
Compilation: cl -c /W3 /nologo  -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_PATHDEF -DWIN32   -DFEAT_CSCOPE -DFEAT_NETBEANS_INTG   -DFEAT_XPM_W32   -DWINVER=0x0400 -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0400  /Fo.\ObjGOLYHTR/ /Ox /GL -DNDEBUG  /Zl /MT -DFEAT_OLE -DFEAT_MBYTE_IME -DDYNAMIC_IME -DFEAT_GUI_W32 -DDYNAMIC_ICONV -DDYNAMIC_GETTEXT -DFEAT_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL -DDYNAMIC_TCL_DLL=\"tcl83.dll\" -DDYNAMIC_TCL_VER=\"8.3\" -DFEAT_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON_DLL=\"python27.dll\" -DFEAT_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3 -DDYNAMIC_PYTHON3_DLL=\"python31.dll\" -DFEAT_PERL -DDYNAMIC_PERL -DDYNAMIC_PERL_DLL=\"perl512.dll\" -DFEAT_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_VER=191 -DDYNAMIC_RUBY_DLL=\"msvcrt-ruby191.dll\" -DFEAT_BIG /Fd.\ObjGOLYHTR/ /Zi
Linking: link /RELEASE /nologo /subsystem:windows /LTCG:STATUS oldnames.lib kernel32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib gdi32.lib  comdlg32.lib ole32.lib uuid.lib /machine:i386 /nodefaultlib gdi32.lib version.lib   winspool.lib comctl32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib  /machine:i386 /nodefaultlib libcmt.lib oleaut32.lib  user32.lib      /nodefaultlib:python27.lib /nodefaultlib:python31.lib   e:\tcl\lib\tclstub83.lib WSock32.lib e:\xpm\lib\libXpm.lib /PDB:gvim.pdb -debug

--- Options ---
  autoread            balloondelay=400    fileformat=unix     mousemodel=extend   syntax=sh           verbose=1
  autowrite           ballooneval         filetype=sh         scroll=18           tabstop=4           window=48
  background=dark     commentstring=#%s   helplang=nl         shiftwidth=4      notextmode          nowrap
  balloonexpr=GTranslator()
  directory=C:\cygwin\tmp
  indentexpr=GetShIndent()
  indentkeys=0{,0},!^F,o,O,e,0=then,0=do,0=else,0=elif,0=fi,0=esac,0=done,),0=;;,0=;&,0=fin,0=fil,0=fip,0=fir,0=fix,=end,=else,=cat,=fina,=END,0\

  fileencoding=
  fileencodings=ucs-bom
```

Comment: I should give `gVim7.3` a try. Thanks

Comment: It is also a good idea to put `scriptencoding utf-8` at the very start of script with non-ascii characters.

Comment: @ZyX: You ought to have a blog somewhere with those fantastic nuggets. How _do you_ get them?